# Compare date only (without time) in JPA2 (JPQL)

Tags: datetime, jpa, date, jpa-2.0, jpql

Im trying to compare `Calendar`s with JPA2. The query looks somewhat like that:

```
TypedQuery<X> q = em.createQuery("select r from Record r where r.calendar= :calendar", X.class);
Calendar c = foo(); // setting fields and stuff
q.setParameter("calendar", c);
```

This, however, compares the date + time. I want to know if MM:DD:YYYY is equal and do not care about the time. Is there a nice way to do that in JPA2 or do I have to create a native query?

I tried setting HH:MM:SS:... to zero before saving it in the db but I don't know if this is very wise, regarding time zones and daylight saving and stuff.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
q.setParameter("calendar", c, TemporalType.DATE)
```

You can pass the TemporalType.DATE to setParameter method to truncate the date+time.

Comment: i think its not working when you have @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) annotation on the column definition in the entity. Do you know how to fix this case?

Comment: This is NOT working when we have @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) annotation on the column definition in the entity.

Answer (score 9):

There is no mention of DateTime functions allowing to do that in the spec of JPQL, but you could always cheat and do

```
select r from Record r where r.calendar >= :theDayAtZeroOClock and r.calendar < :theDayAfterAtZeroOClock
```

Answer (score 7):

Mysql and H2 compatible comparison of dates ignoring time part:

```
`@Query("SELECT DISTINCT s " +
        "FROM Session s " +
        "JOIN s.movie m " +
        "WHERE m.id = :movie AND CAST(s.time AS date) = CAST(:date AS date) " +
        "ORDER BY s.time")
List<Session> getByMovieAndDate(@Param("movie") Long movie, @Param("date") LocalDateTime date);`
```

Answer (score 6):

When using an Oracle database, you can use the `trunc` function in your JPQL query, e.g.:

```
TypedQuery<X> q = em.createQuery("select r from Record r where trunc(r.calendar) = trunc(:calendar)", X.class);
```

See also https://cirovladimir.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/jpa-trunc-date-in-jpql-query-oracle/

Answer (score 0):

I had to use date_trunc on the where clause:

```
    TypedQuery<X> q = em.createQuery("select r from Record r where date_trunc('day',r).calendar= :calendar", X.class);
Calendar c = foo(); // setting fields and stuff
q.setParameter("calendar", c, TemporalType.DATE);
```

Comment: Which provider are you using?

Comment: i'm using hibernate

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate 6 and above, you can use `date_trunc(text, timestamp)` to truncate the timestamp more precisely, for example:

`date_trunc('hour', timestamp)` to truncate the timestamp up to the hour (no minutes and no seconds).